# Are Time-sharing and multi-tasking operating systems same or different

Tags: operating-systems, os-kernel

My question is regarding time-sharing and multi-tasking systems.

Time-sharing operating system assigns time slot to each task while multi-tasking OS runs various jobs in parallel.

But as I get it, on a single processor system, time-sharing is the only way to achieve multi-tasking.  (I don't know if I am correct on this premise.)

So, are time-sharing and multi-tasking system same or different.
And if they are different, then what are the key differences (particularly on a single-processor/single-core system with no hyper-threading support etc) ?

Thanks

Comment: They are same. The term time-sharing operating system is now obsolete and now only the term Multi-tasking operating system is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Just as multiprogramming allows the processor to handle multiple batch jobs at a time, multiprogramming can also be used to handle multiple interactive jobs. In this latter case, the technique is reffered to as **time sharing**, because processor time is shared among multiple users. In a time-sharing system, multiple users simultaneously access the system through terminals, with the OS interleaving the execution of each user program in a short burst or quantum of computation.

[William Stallings, Operating Systems Internals and Design Principles, 7th Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013230998X)

You should keep in mind that the principal objective of a time sharing system is not to maximize processor use, but to minimize response time.

I think it would be correct however to assert that on a single processor system, multi-tasking is achieved through time sharing. Remember that a processor can execute only one task at a time at any given time.